# PHP Display Values from Object within an Array Based on Key

Tags: php, arrays, object, drupal-7

I have the following array which contains both objects and arrays. How do I get only the specific values (for each object)  based on their keys?
I've tested and the array is displaying (see below) but I cannot isolate the 'name" value as needed.

I have tried the following code to get the name value:

```
case 'field_prgm_housing' :
$node = 'field_color';
$tids =  field_get_items('node', $node, $key, $node->language);
$terms = taxonomy_term_load_multiple(array(), array('tid' => $tids));
$nameonly = $terms->[0]->name[0];
return = $nameonly;
break;      
Colors (Array, 2 elements)
    12 (Object) stdClass
      tid (String, 2 characters ) 12
      vid (String, 1 characters ) 3
      name (String, 9 characters ) Blue
      description (String, 0 characters )
      format (String, 13 characters ) filtered_html
      weight (String, 1 characters ) 0
      vocabulary_machine_name (String, 15 characters ) colors
      rdf_mapping (Array, 5 elements)
      path (Array, 1 element)
    13 (Object) stdClass
      tid (String, 2 characters ) 13
      vid (String, 1 characters ) 3
      name (String, 8 characters ) Green
      description (String, 0 characters )
      format (String, 13 characters ) filtered_html
      weight (String, 1 characters ) 0
      vocabulary_machine_name (String, 15 characters ) colors
      rdf_mapping (Array, 5 elements)
      path (Array, 1 element)
```

Comment: If the array's output is the var_dump of $terms: this one should work $terms[$i]->name. (Just replace $i with the relevant key)

Comment: `$names = Array_column($array, "name")` is that what you are looking for

Comment: @OfirBaruch in this case what would be the relevant key if not name?

Comment: According to your example $i should be 12 or 13. But since this data is dynamic you should find a way to get it by using a loop or a sort of a condition.

Comment: @Andreas In this case "$arrray" would be terms correct?  
'$nameonly =  Array_column($terms, "name");' returns an empty array

Comment: @OfirBaruch that works if I know the initial TID value. How could I change it to the order instead of value?

Comment: So it's not a json text that you can make an array instead of object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Try this


    $node = 'field_color';
    $tids =  field_get_items('node', $node, $key, $node->language);
    $terms = taxonomy_term_load_multiple(array(), array('tid' => $tids));

    //loop all the values and get the require value
   $name = array();
    foreach($terms as $term){
          $name[] = $term->name;
    }
    return $name;
```

Comment: I'm operating within switch statements, for each throws errors.

Comment: I need to use the values elsewhere hence when I them to be available as the $nameonly variable; is this possible with foreach?

Comment: Here is what I've tried so far but its only showing the first value:

 foreach($terms as $term){
                                $name=$term->name;
                                }
                                $return[$key] = $name;

Comment: $name = array();
    foreach($terms as $term){
          $name[] = $term->name;
    }
    return $name;

Answer (score 0):

What `$terms->[0]` suppose to mean?

`$terms` is an array, so you have to access it by specifying the index you want to get, like: `$terms[12], $terms[13]`...

Elements of that array are object so when you get one you have to use "->" operator to get it's field (or method).

So it has to be like:

```
$nameonly = $terms[12]->name;
$nameonly = $terms[13]->name;
```

Or you can iterate trough all the array items, as @kranthi suggested.